# R not valid variable name for caret function

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to use train caret function to investigate xgboost results

```
#open file with train data
trainy <- read.csv('')
# open file with test data
test <- read.csv('')

# we dont need ID column

##### Removing IDs
trainy$ID <- NULL
test.id <- test$ID
test$ID <- NULL

##### Extracting TARGET
trainy.y <- trainy$TARGET

trainy$TARGET <- NULL


# set up the cross-validated hyper-parameter search
xgb_grid_1 = expand.grid(
  nrounds = 1000,
  eta = c(0.01, 0.001, 0.0001),
  max_depth = c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10),
  gamma = 1
)

# pack the training control parameters
xgb_trcontrol_1 = trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  returnData = FALSE,
  returnResamp = "all",                                                        # save losses across all models
  classProbs = TRUE,                                                           # set to TRUE for AUC to be computed
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
  allowParallel = TRUE
)

# train the model for each parameter combination in the grid, 
#   using CV to evaluate
xgb_train_1 = train(
  x = as.matrix(trainy),
  y = as.factor(trainy.y),
  trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,
  tuneGrid = xgb_grid_1,
  method = "xgbTree"
)
```

I see this error

```
Error in train.default(x = as.matrix(trainy), y = as.factor(trainy.y), trControl = xgb_trcontrol_1,  : 
  At least one of the class levels is not a valid R variable name;
```

I have looked at other cases but still cant understand what I should change? R is quite different from Python for me for now

As I can see I should do something with y classes variable, but what and how exactly ? Why didnt  as.factor function work?

Comment: Perhaps provide a minimum working example (including data) that causes this error?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff Didnt I specify the exact error? And actions I tried to do? If not, then I am really confused

Comment: *... must include ... the shortest code necessary to reproduce [the error]*.  Your code is not reproducible.  You would need to include some data so we can see what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, hope it will help to all novices

I needed to transofm all data to factor type in the way like

```
trainy[] <- lapply(trainy, factor)
```